# Find antiderivative of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Consider the function
$$
f(x) =\begin{cases}
  x-\frac{1}{2}, \quad 0\le x<1 \\[5pt]
  x-v-\frac{1}{2}, \quad v \le x < v+1\ (v\in \mathbb{N})
 \end{cases}
$$
This function  is certainly integrable as it only has a countably many discontinuities. For finding it's antiderivative, can I simply consider the piecewise functions, meaning I would obtain for example
$$
F(x) =\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{2}x, \quad 0\le x<1 \\[5pt]
  \frac{1}{2}x^2-vx-\frac{1}{2}x, \quad v \le x < v+1\ (v\in \mathbb{N})
 \end{cases}
$$
or is this procedure incorrect?

Comment: I'm confused; since $v=2$ is allowed, the function is not defined in $1<x<2$ ?! (the same is true for any $v\geq 2$)

Comment: @MattiP. for $x = 1.5$ you would have $v = 1$?

Comment: I think you’d need to be careful when using this for an integration over the boundary. I expect that the integral $\int_0^2 f(x)\,dx$ would need to be evaluated by $F_1(1)-F(0)+F(2)-F_2(1)$ where $F_1(1)$ is my made up notation to say $\lim_{x\to1^-}F(x)$ and $F_2$ is the direct substitution for the other side of the boundary, since the second piecewise function has equality with $1$: $F_2(1)=F(1)$.

Comment: Luckily in your case, the integral over any entire piece $v\le x\lt v+1$ is exactly zero, so you’d only need to integrate within a single piece to get an integral over many pieces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you describe is a saw tooth curve, where for each $v=0,1,2,\cdots$ the graph is a straight line from coordinate $(v,-1/2)$ to $(v,1/2)$.  Thus if
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)dt
$$
over the range $[0,v]$ for a positive integer $v$, you will have $F(v) = 0$.  In general if $x = v+ \xi$ where $v$ is an an integer $0,1,2, \cdots$ and $0 \leqslant \xi < 1$, you have
\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_0^v f(t) dt + \int_v^x f(t) dt \\
&= 0 + \left[ \tfrac{1}{2}t^2 - vt -\tfrac{1}{2}t\right]_v^{v+\xi} \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2} \xi^2 -\tfrac{1}{2}\xi
\end{align}
This can be written using the integer part operator, for $x \geqslant 0$,
\begin{align}
F(x) = \tfrac{1}{2}(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}(x - \lfloor x \rfloor)
\end{align}
which is not the same as the expression you derived.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I stupidly treated the function in a completely incorrect way!

Comment: Is there a "simple" way how would you integrate the newly obtained function $F(x)$ or will this become much  harder than the integration of $f(x)$?

Comment: It is harder but the same approach works.  The graph of $ F(x)$ consists of U shaped segments from coordinates $(v,0)$ to $(v+1,0)$, so the integral over a general range will be a sum of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ negative constants (one for each complete U) plus a residual representing the fractional part of the argument.  You can repeat again and again but each case the expression will become more complicated.

Comment: For the integral of $F(x)$ I would obtain: 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} F(x) = -\frac{1}{12}
$$


$$
 \int_{0}^{x} F(x) = \frac{1}{6}x^3 - \frac{1}{4}x^2, \quad 0 \le x < 1
$$


$$
\int_{0}^{x} F(x) = \frac{1}{6}\left(x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor\right)^3
 -\frac{1}{4}\left(x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor\right)^2
  - \frac{1}{12}\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor,
 \quad x \in  \mathbb{R}
$$

Comment: Now I understand why one chooses the Bernoulli polynomials the way one does, since when adding the $-\frac{1}{12}$ we get an integral of $0$ over the period which preserves the periodicity of the function. Without this constant term the functions would no longer behave periodically  after this last  integration steps and hence became hard to handle.

Comment: the integral above should of course depend on some other variable than $x$